# Write infotype text programmatically

Tags: abap, sap-hr

I need to create/write a text in an infotype via ABAP code. So I'm looking for a function module or some "clean" solution for this.
Right now I only found this [post](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/287600) with a "quick&dirty" solution.

I'm a bit afraid to change something directly from the cluster so I hope maybe someone can offer me another way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/04/30/update-long-text-in-infotypes/) will help you. It's the most modular and OO possibility I've came across yet.

Here is a sample code:

```
    DATA: lo_0194         TYPE REF TO cl_hrpa_infotype_0194,
          lw_pernr        TYPE p_pernr,
          fr_msg_handler  TYPE REF TO if_hrpa_message_handler,
          lr_message_list TYPE REF TO cl_hrpa_message_list,
          ls_container    TYPE  hrpad_infty_container_ref,
          lr_contain_0194 TYPE REF TO cl_hrpa_infotype_container,
          lr_upd_cluster  TYPE REF TO cl_hrpa_text_cluster,
          lt_text_194     TYPE hrpad_text_tab.
```

**creating infotype object**

```
    CREATE OBJECT lr_message_list.
    fr_msg_handler  = lr_message_list.
    TRY.
        CREATE OBJECT lo_0194
          EXPORTING
            tclas = 'A'
            infty = '0194'.
      CATCH cx_hrpa_violated_assertion INTO DATA(ls_exp).
        DATA(lw_message) = ls_exp->get_text( ).
    ENDTRY.
    IF lw_message IS INITIAL.
      "error handling
    ENDIF.
```

**modifying data**

```
    APPEND 'TEXT' TO lt_text_194.
    TRY.
        lr_contain_0194 ?= ls_container.
        lr_contain_0194->modify_text_tab( lt_text_194 ).
      CATCH cx_hrpa_violated_assertion INTO ls_exp.
        lw_message = ls_exp->get_text( ).
    ENDTRY.

    TRY.
        lo_0194->if_hrpa_infty_bl~modify(
           EXPORTING
             old_container   = lr_contain_0194
             massn           = space
             massg           = space
             update_mode     = VALUE hrpad_update_mode( )
             no_auth_check   = ''
             message_handler = fr_msg_handler
          IMPORTING
           is_ok             = DATA(lw_ok)
          CHANGING
            container       = ls_container ).
      CATCH cx_hrpa_violated_assertion INTO ls_exp.
        lw_message = ls_exp->get_text( ).
    ENDTRY.
```

**updating cluster**

```
    CREATE OBJECT lr_upd_cluster.
    TRY.
        CALL METHOD lr_upd_cluster->update
          EXPORTING
            tclas         = 'A'
            pskey         = VALUE pskey( )
            histo         = abap_true
            uname         = sy-uname
            aedtm         = sy-datum
            pgmid         = VALUE old_prog( )
            text_tab      = lt_text_194
            no_auth_check = abap_true.
      CATCH   cx_hrpa_violated_assertion.
    ENDTRY.
```

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on SO - could you add an outline of the solution to your answer?